# Integrate valgrind in qt creator

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator, valgrind, analyzer

I'm wondering why I can't use the valgrind analyizer from inside my Qt Creator.
Valgrind is installed and runs from command line, but is not present in Qt Creator.

Does someone else have this issue?

QtCreator 2.01 Based on Qt 4.7.0 (64 bit)
Ubuntu 11.04 x64
g++-4.5

Is the QtCreator version too old?

Comment: What does it mean "not present"? Don't you have the `Analyze` button on the left pane?

Comment: exactly!No button Analyze at all, while on both the Mac and windows versions I have it! Very strange.

Comment: You need a newer Qt Creator. Valgrind support in Qt Creator was added in version 2.2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated before, Qt Creator support for Valgrind began in version 2.2.  I'd suggest an upgrade and it should work for you.

Let us know how it goes...

Comment: Yes, it works now by updating. The bad thing is that I didn't found the latest version on the Ubuntu official repositories, so I installed it without the typical apt-get install dance...